# My if statement is not working properly

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdf

The if statement is not working properly it will print one page correctly then it prints 17 more pages without column titles and just one data row. I have not been able to figure out way this is not working correctly. Is there a better way to do this. The way I am doing the break handling I got of the FPDF Site.

Link to a PDF file to show what this code produces http://notaryaccounting.com/testpdf.pdf

```
   $pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage ($orientation='', $format='', $keepmargins=false, $tocpage=false);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(true);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(true);   
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(10, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, 10);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'BI', 20, '', 'false');
$year = date("Y"); ;
$html = 'Mileage for signing1 dates from 1/1/' .$year. ' to 12/31/' .$year. '';
$pdf->SetXY(2, 15);
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 8, '', true);
$pdf->writeHTML ($html, $ln=true, $fill=false, $reseth=false, $cell=false, $align='R');


//set initial y axis position per page
$y_axis_initial = 20;

//print column titles
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
$pdf->SetX(10);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'Invoice #:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(27,6,'Signing Date:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Name:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(60,6,'Location:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(15,6,'Start:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(15,6,'End:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'Mileage:',1,0,'L',1);

//Go to next row
 $y_axis = 26;
 $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

//initialize counter
$i = 0;

//Set maximum rows per page
$max = 25;

//Set Row Height
$row_height = 6;





$result = $db->query("SELECT invoicenumber,signstart,fname,lname,street1,city,state,mstart,mend FROM signings1 WHERE pid = $pid ORDER by signstart"); 
foreach($result as $key => $sig) {
   $totalcont = $totalcont + 1;
   echo $i;
  //If the current row is the last one, create new page and print column title
        if ($i == $max){

        $pdf->AddPage();

        //print column titles for the current page
        $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
        $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
        $pdf->SetX(05);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Invoice #:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(27,6,'Signing Date:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,'Name:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(60,6,'Location:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,'Start:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,'End:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Mileage:',1,0,'L',1);

         //Go to next row
       $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

       //Set $i variable to 0 (first row)
       $i = 0;


    }



        $invoicenumber = $sig[invoicenumber];   
        $signdate=phpdate($sig[signstart]);
        $name = $sig[fname] . ' ' . $sig[lname];
        $location = $sig[street1] . " " . $sig[city] . " " . $sig[state];
        $mstart  = $sig[mstart];
        $mend  = $sig[mend];
        $miles  = $sig[miles];
        $miles1 = $mend - $mstart; 
        $subTotal += $miles1;
        $totalmoney = $subTotal * .56;

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
        $pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
        $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
        $pdf->SetX(10);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$invoicenumber,1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(27,6,$signdate,1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,$name,1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(60,6,$location,1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,$mstart,1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,$mend,1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$miles1,1,0,'L',1);

    //Go to next row
    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
    $i = $i + 1;
}

ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: I didn't touch the original code apart from removing the errors and checking that the page break works correctly. I will go and have a look at it and see if i can make sense of it. I will get back to you with some sort of information about it. It may be tomorrow as it is evening here. I haven't played with pdf output before so i am learning new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing major wrong with this. a few sillies of undefined variables. I have changed the names of some of the variables but there was nothing wrong that i could spot with the original ones.

I do not have the 'Arial' font installed as i just downloaded and installed the original 'tcpdf' software.

It now page breaks correctly.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ .'/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
require __DIR__ .'/tcpdf/tcpdf_autoconfig.php';
$pid = 1;

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testmysql';
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
);
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


// $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'testmysql');

$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->AddPage ($orientation='', $format='', $keepmargins=false, $tocpage=false);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(true);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(true);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(10, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, 10);

$pdf->SetFont('arial', 'BI', 20, '', 'false');
$year = date("Y"); ;
$html = 'Mileage for signing1 dates from 1/1/' .$year. ' to 12/31/' .$year. '';
$pdf->SetXY(2, 15);
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 8, '', true);
$pdf->writeHTML ($html, $ln=true, $fill=false, $reseth=false, $cell=false, $align='R');


//set initial y axis position per page
$y_axis_initial = 20;

//print column titles
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
$pdf->SetFont('arial','B',12);
$pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
$pdf->SetX(10);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'Invoice #:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(27,6,'Signing Date:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Name:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(60,6,'Location:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(15,6,'Start:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(15,6,'End:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'Mileage:',1,0,'L',1);

//Set Row Height
$row_height = 6;

$totalcount = 0;
$subTotal = 0;
$miles = 0;

//Go to next row
 $y_axis = 26;
 $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

//initialize counter
$pageLine = 0;

//Set maximum rows per page
$itemsPerPage = 3 /*25 */;

//
$result = $db->query("SELECT invoicenumber,signstart,fname,lname,street1,city,state,mstart,mend FROM signings1 WHERE pid = $pid ORDER by signstart");
foreach($result as $key => $sig) {
//    var_dump($key, $sig);
   $totalcount = $totalcount + 1;
   echo $pageLine;
  //If the current row is the last one, create new page and print column title
        if ($pageLine >= $itemsPerPage) {

        $pdf->AddPage();

        //print column titles for the current page
        $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
        $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
        $pdf->SetFont('arial','B',12);
        $pdf->SetX(05);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Invoice #:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(27,6,'Signing Date:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,'Name:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(60,6,'Location:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,'Start:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,'End:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Mileage:',1,0,'L',1);

        $subTotal = 0;
        //Go to next row
       $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

       //Set $pageLine variable to 0 (first row)
       $pageLine = 0;
   }

        $invoicenumber = $sig['invoicenumber'];
        $signdate=date($sig['signstart']);
        $name = $sig['fname'] . ' ' . $sig['lname'];
        $location = $sig['street1'] . " " . $sig['city'] . " " . $sig['state'];
        $mstart  = $sig['mstart'];
        $mend  = $sig['mend'];
        $miles = $mend - $mstart;
        // $miles  =  $sig['miles'];
        $subTotal += $miles;
        $totalmoney = $subTotal * .56;

        $pdf->SetFont('arial','B',9);
        $pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
        $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
        $pdf->SetX(10);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$invoicenumber,1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(27,6,$signdate,1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(30,6,$name,1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(60,6,$location,1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,$mstart,1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,$mend,1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$miles,1,0,'L',1);

    //Go to next row
    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
    $pageLine = $pageLine + 1;
}

ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: It works a lot better than before don't now what you did. But it still does not break on the second page correctly it looks like its adding 25 blank lines and then prints the next 25 lines. Then it creates a 3rd page because of were the 2nd set of lines appear. It also moves to the left a tiny bit each time it creates a new page. This is a link so you can see http://notaryaccounting.com/expencetest1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Change `if ($i == $max){`  into `if ($i != 0 && $i % $max == 0) {`
This will execute the ,,new page'' each 25 records  the `$i != 0` is there to ensure new page wouldnt be added to the 1st record.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out way the pages where putting all the data way down on the page on all the other pages after the first one.
With the help of Ryan Vincent answer who helped me with the script printing 17 pages using his examples above. 
I still had one problem it was putting all the data way down the page. So right after

```
if ($pageLine >= $itemsPerPage) {

        $pdf->AddPage();\
```

I added

```
$y_axis = 20; //reset Y_axis to move the data back to the top of the NEW page
                      //under the columns
```

That is all it took and now the script works perfect

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage ($orientation='', $format='', $keepmargins=false, $tocpage=false);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(true);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(true);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(10, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, 10);



//set initial y axis position per page
$y_axis = 20;

//print column titles
$pdf->addmileagetext();
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
$pdf->SetFont('arial','B',12);
$pdf->SetY($y_axis);
$pdf->SetX(10);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'Invoice #:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'Date:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(40,6,'Name:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(60,6,'Location:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(15,6,'Start:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(15,6,'End:',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'Mileage:',1,0,'L',1);

//Set Row Height
$row_height = 6;


//Go to next row

 $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

//initialize counter
$pageLine = 0;

//Set maximum rows per page
$itemsPerPage = 25;

//
$result = $db->query("SELECT invoicenumber,signstart,fname,lname,street1,city,state,mstart,mend FROM signings1 WHERE pid = $pid ORDER by signstart");
foreach($result as $key => $sig) {
   //var_dump($key, $sig);




  //If the current row is the last one, create new page and print column title
        if ($pageLine >= $itemsPerPage) {

        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->addmileagetext();

        $y_axis = 20; //reset Y_axis to move the data back to the top of the NEW page
                      //under the columns
        //print column titles for the current page
        $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
        $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
        $pdf->SetFont('arial','B',12);
        $pdf->SetX(10);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Invoice #:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Date:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(40,6,'Name:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(60,6,'Location:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,'Start:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,'End:',1,0,'L',1);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Mileage:',1,0,'L',1);

        $subTotal = 0;
        //Go to next row
       $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

       //Set $pageLine variable to 0 (first row)
       $pageLine = 0;

        }

        $invoicenumber = $sig['invoicenumber'];
        $signdate=phpdate($sig['signstart']);
        $name = $sig['fname'] . ' ' . $sig['lname'];
        $location = $sig['street1'] . " " . $sig['city'] . " " . $sig['state'];
        $mstart  = $sig['mstart'];
        $mend  = $sig['mend'];
        $miles = $mend - $mstart;
        $totalcount = $totalcount + 1;
        $subTotal += $miles;
        $totalmoney = $subTotal * .56;

        $pdf->SetFont('arial','B',9);
        $pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
        $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
        $pdf->SetX(10);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$invoicenumber,1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$signdate,1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->Cell(40,6,$name,1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->Cell(60,6,$location,1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,$mstart,1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->Cell(15,6,$mend,1,0,'L',0);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$miles,1,0,'L',0);


    //Go to next row
    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
    $pageLine = $pageLine + 1;




}

ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output();
```